# Adding custom button to MPMoviePlayerController (fullscreen)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a `MPMoviePlayerController` instance in my iOS app, that plays a local file in fullscreen mode. This all works fine, but now I want to add a custom button to the window for changing the playback speed. We support both iPhone and iPad in all orientations.

I know how to set the playback speed from code (using `setCurrentPlaybackRate`), but I need to let the user do it while watching the video, which means adding some kind of button to the playback screen next to the existing buttons, e.g. next to "play", "pause", or in the top bar.

By looking on StackOverflow I have found various replies for questions similar but not quite the same, some saying it cannot be done in fullscreen, some saying it can be done (but is very complex) by creating some kind of overlay, effectively replacing the entire overlay with a custom one.

Although, I have yet to find any code examples (apart from a few snippets without context), getting-started style tutorial or similar for this, so any pointers to example code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this Apple example could help you

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but after looking into that example, it does not add custom buttons. I noticed, that the buttons are different when playing local vs streaming media, but those are just iOS default buttons still, unfortunately.